# How to optimize code for Oracle case when condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My SQL has two result fields according to the same condition. Now I have to write it two times. I wonder whether the database compiler has already optimized the code automatically or if I have to change the other way to optimize the SQL?

```
select id,parent_id as p_Id,name,
(case when exists(select * from t_group t2 where t1.id=t2.parent_id) 
then 2 else 1 end) type,
(case when exists(select * from t_group t2 where t1.id=t2.parent_id) 
then 'true' else 'false' end) as is_Parent
from t_group t1
```

I have tried to change it like this, but failed.

```
select id,parent_id as p_Id,name,
(case when exists(select * from t_group t2 where t1.id=t2.parent_id) 
then 2 else 1 end) type,
(case when type==1 
then 'true' else 'false' end) as is_Parent
from t_group t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common table expression or an inline view to get the expression once and then use it outside of that CTE or inline view.  Here is what I mean, using an inline view:

```
SELECT v.id, v.parent_id, v.name, v.type, case when v.type = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END is_parent 
FROM 
(
select id,parent_id as p_Id,name,
(case when exists(select * from t_group t2 where t1.id=t2.parent_id) 
then 2 else 1 end) type
from t_group t1
) v
```

Comment: Do you need to provide a name for the 'inline view'?  You would in many systems, and standard SQL requires it, but Oracle may not.

Comment: No, you do not.  But you do if you want to refer to its columns and there is ambiguity.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it using a left join to avoid multiple queries being executed per row, while making sure that the left joined derived table can never return more than one row:

```
select t.id, 
       t.parent_id as p_id,
       t.name,
       case when c.parent_id is not null then 2 else 1 end as type,
       case when c.parent_id is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as is_parent
  from t_group t
  left join (select parent_id,
                    row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by null) as rn
               from t_group) c
    on c.parent_id = t.id
   and c.rn = 1
```

Comment: I don't think that's the most efficient way.  If you are worried about the semi join being a nested loop, you could `SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM t_group` in a common table expression and left join to that.  I believe that'd be less buffer gets, on average.  This sort of thing is why Oracle needs explicit join syntax for semi joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,parent_id as p_Id,name,
       decode(t2.parent_id,NULL,1,2) type,
       decode(t2.parent_id,NULL,'false','true') is_Parent
  from t_group t1
  left join(select distinct parent_id from t_group) t2
    on t1.id=t2.parent_id
```

If exists index on column parent_id then optimizer issues 'index range scan' (as  with a subquery in select) or 'index fast full scan' (if  understanding that it is faster).